# python cherrypy - how to add header

Tags: python, cherrypy

How can I add retry-header in cherrypy?

```
  import cherrypy
  import os

  class Root:

    def index(self):
      cherrypy.response.headers['Retry-After'] = 60
      cherrypy.request.headers["Age"]= 20
      cherrypy.config.update({'Retry-After': '60'})

      raise cherrypy.HTTPError(503, 'Service Unavailable')
    index.exposed = True 

    cherrypy.quickstart(Root())
```

This retry-header dt works.

Comment: Just a little suggestion: The common indentation level in python is 4 spaces - you might want to follow it instead of using 2 spaces.

Comment: ok thanks. can you help me in getting answer of my question?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

When you set a status code by raising `HTTPError`, the headers in `cherrypy.response.headers` are ignored.  Set the HTTP status by setting `cherrypy.response.status` instead:

```
import cherrypy

class Root:
    def index(self):
        cherrypy.response.headers['Retry-After'] = 60
        cherrypy.response.status = 503
        # Feel free to return a better error page than the following
        return "<h1>Service Unavailable</h1>"
    index.exposed = True

cherrypy.quickstart(Root())
```

Comment: You're welcome! If the answer solved your problem, please consider accepting it to show others that your question has been answered and to give credit for the answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work